# C#:Accessing initialized member of static class instance returns NULL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton, nullreferenceexception

I am developing an Item system for Unity and I am trying to reason about XML file manipulation. I have an ItemDatabase class as shown below:

```
[XmlRoot("ItemDatabase")]
public class ItemDatabase
{
    // List that contains all Game Items.
    // Members must be Serializable. Use Editor workflow
    // to create an item Adder/Remover for the Database.
    [XmlArray("Items"), XmlArrayItem("BaseGameItem")]
    public List<BaseGameItem> Items = new List<BaseGameItem>();

    // Singleton Pattern. Only one instance will be initialized.
    public static ItemDatabase itemDb;

    public ItemDatabase()
    {
        if(itemDb == null)
        itemDb = this;
    }

    // Saves the Item List to an XML file.
    public void Save(string filepath)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemDatabase));

        // Disposable Pattern
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            // Check if path was valid.
            if (stream != null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    // Loads an existing Item List from an XML file.
    public static ItemDatabase Load(string filepath)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemDatabase));

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                ItemDatabase db = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as ItemDatabase;
                stream.Close();
                return db;
            }

            // Return null if the file cannot be read/found.
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Recently, I got exposed to a very basic implementation of the Singleton pattern, which makes sense for me to use for something like a database. The instance of the class is static, whereas the List is initialized above.

However, I then try to access this class using a GUI I called the DatabaseManager class. The relevant implementation is shown below:

```
public class ItemDatabaseManager : EditorWindow
{
    // List of items from database.
    List<BaseGameItem> items;

    // Item template to add/remove from database.
    // To be filled by user.
    BaseGameItem itemToAdd;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        items = ItemDatabase.itemDb.Items;
    }
```

My thought process led me to believe that:

1. There shall be one instance of ItemDatabase, which in turn implies there will only be one list to manage.
2. Since the List is initialized, I would be able to directly access it from external classes such as the manager.

However, whenever the editor window shows up, I get a Null Reference Exception, indicating that the List of items is null. I have confirmed it is not the ItemDatabase instance. How is it even possible for the List to be empty when it was immediately initialized as part of the class definition? What am I fundamentally overlooking in this scenario? Maybe there is an underlying order of constructors that I am misinterpreting?

Assuming I understand things properly, setting the list to public static fixes that - but it defeats the purpose of keeping the list directly inaccessible?

Comment: Its early, so maybe I am just missing something.  Where do you ever populate the list of Items?  Solely based on your code above you _never_ populate `itemDb.Items` with any data, so of course it will be null.

Comment: It's a code smell when you need a singleton to be deserialized. Don't do that.

Comment: "it was immediately initialized as part of the class definition" that's not true. `Items` is an instance field that gets initialized _when you create an instance_. You don't create an instance anywhere in your client code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are not implementing the singleton pattern correctly because you create the instance in the constructor.
Have a look at [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

Example:

```
public class ItemDatabase
{
   private static ItemDatabase _instance;

   private ItemDatabase() {}

   public static ItemDatabase Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new ItemDatabase();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }

   // ... add the rest of your code
}
```

You can now simply access the singleton with:

```
ItemDatabase.Instance
```

and the instance will be dynamically created on demand at the first access.

EDIT: as per @maccettura comment the code above is **not** thread safe. If you need thread-safety you can use a lock object ([see this article for more info](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)):

```
public class ItemDatabase
{
   private static ItemDatabase _instance;
   private static readonly object _lock = new object();

   private ItemDatabase() {}

   public static ItemDatabase Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         lock (_object)
         {
             if (instance == null)
             {
                instance = new ItemDatabase();
             }
             return instance;
         }
      }
   }

   // ... add the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: FYI your version of the singleton pattern is _not thread safe_.

Comment: @maccettura what do you mean? The `_lock` object is static and private to this class (I will add the `readonly` keyword).

Comment: Take a read through [this excerpt](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) on Singletons from C# in Depth.

Comment: @aghidini I realize I didn't implement the pattern correctly as I was following a more crude overview tutorial. Using your approach seems to fix the problem, but I do not understand why the List is no longer null. Was my itemDb not initialized all along? While the pattern was incorrect, I still thought my instance is initialized to a non-null value anyways.